# RS dependent on Dalvik?

Tags: renderscript, android-runtime

How dependent is Renderscript on the framework being Dalvik or ART?

I was testing a device with 4.4.2 running ART and the app kept crashing. Was only later that I realized it was on ART and switched back to Dalvik. On Dalvik it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not tied together at all; RS is a Java API (same as any other framework API) that calls into a lower level native driver stack. If you've got an application that works under Dalvik but not under ART, you should [file a bug.](https://code.google.com/p/android/)

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll check it further and raise a bug if I'm satisfied that it's not me that's screwed something up.